# How to use formula names in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

When we assign a name to a formula, we have an object (Names("formulaName")) but I don't know how to apply to my code.

I gave a name to a formula like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Names.Add Name:="totalAdd", RefersTo:="=sum(a2:a6)"
```

because I want to retain it between sesions; but when I try to insert it in other cell with:

```
Range("C1").Value = Names("totalAdd").RefersTo
```

I obtain a error 1004 in runtime.
If I refer the formula to Sheet1 like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Names.Add Name:="totalAdd", RefersTo:="=sum(Sheet1!a2:a6)"
```

I obtain the same error.
Why?

Comment: Build your formula manually and use the macro recorder to capture the code that is generated. That will show you a correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm trying to understand formula names. I also could store the formula in a variable and it'd work but it's not my goal the formula itself but the formula names.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The name of your Worksheet")
sht.Range("C1").Value = sht.Evaluate(Application.Names("Name of your Formula").RefersTo))
```

Comment: This one's better than mine. In C1 is the value of the formula not the formula. Thanks a lot.

Comment: However, the background problem was the same this code doesn't work if the name is LOCAL.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the error. The first line of code created a formula name but **LOCAL**; the name only was available in Sheet1. To creating a formula name **GLOBAL** the property Names have to start from Workbooks. My code now:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="totalAdd", RefersTo:="=sum(Sheet1!a2:a6)"
WS.Range("a1").Value = Names("totalAdd").RefersTo
```

Works!
Thank you very much.

Comment: You are using Relative Names because the reference in your formula contains no fixing $. This means you will get a different formula each time you use it in a different location. Relative names are tricky to define and use - I recommend using R1C1 mode to make them easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I've started to learn R1C1 formulas. I think it's the sensible way to deal references though they're harder to understand at the beginning. The book of Bill Jelen is clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

exemples

To refer to à Worksheets2, use Worksheets(2) or Worksheets("Feuil2")

each object may have its own objects. For exemple, Excel has Worksheets that have sheets that have ranges. 
To refer to a sheet, use :

to refer to sheet2, use Worksheets(2) ou Worksheets("sheet2")

To refer to a range, use :

Application.Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Feuil2").Range("A1")

*other exemple; to pt value 1O in a range A1 use

Range("A1").Value = 10

*to hide the cheet2

Worksheets("sheet2").Visible = False

to make it visible again
Sub Essai6()
Worksheets("sheet2").Visible = True
End Sub